# Modifying my htacess to redirect to SSL URL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

My current `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 /~mysite-net/vlog http://www.example.net/vlog
Redirect 301 /~mysite-net/pp https://www.example.net/pp
Redirect 301 /~mysite-net/pp02 https://www.example.net/pp02
Redirect 301 /~mysite-net/pp03 https://www.example.net/pp03
Redirect 301 /~mysite-net/ http://www.example.net/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+).html$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\?s=([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ %1?%2%3 [L,R=301]
```

this does what intended so no problem. However, now I need to modify it so it always redirects to the SSL version of my site. It means no matter if the user types http it will always redirect them to https instead.

So I just added these lines at the bottom:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R,L]
```

but it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

May be this can be work 
I think you forgot to put   `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That goes instead the last 3 lines I added?

Comment: but i cannot see RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on  this line

Comment: add in at bottom where you added your last three line add with them

Comment: After those 3 lines?

Comment: ya or above three line

Comment: Well, I found a little problem. If I enter the URL http://example.net/about it redirects to http://example.net/index.php?s=about it should not change the last part

Comment: This rule needs to be added as topmost rule and make sure to clear browser cache.

Comment: "forgot to put  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`" - The OP is using `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` instead, which essentially means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> So I just added these lines at the bottom:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R,L]
> ```

There are two problems with your existing directives:

- You have put them in the wrong place in your file - they need to go at the top, not the bottom. By placing them at the end of the file they will only get processed when requesting static resources, because the preceding directives will otherwise "catch" the URL.
- You are trying to combine the non-www to www redirect in this directive as well, however, you have omitted the `OR` flag on the first condition, so it will never redirect requests for `http://www.example.net/foo`.

In other words, at the *top* of your file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` condition mentioned in the other answer is simply an alternative to your `SERVER_PORT` condition.